# Sync recent achievements reputation notifications and reputation in the activity tab

Tags: discussion, feature-request, notifications

What's the point of keeping the reputation gained count in the activity tab after already seeing it through the navigation bar?

[image: notifications... everywhere]

It also appears here:

[image: notifications... everywhere]

Can we please sync these notifications?

General request: Maybe we can also sync other notifications (like responses).

Comment: Please don't. I actually like it. It feels like there is more reputation. You know, us peasants do enjoy each and every one of these points ;)

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier that's what the system wants you to think ;)

Comment: Well it does seem kind of redundant to have it multiple places.

Comment: The rep tab is useful when you're capped for the day, but are curious about which of your answers people are looking at (especially if someone linked one of your answers somewhere that gets a lot of traffic).  I forget if the blue counter still updates with no-rep upvotes or not.